# MongoDB 2.6 suddenly stopped in Amazon ECS (got signal 15 (Terminated), will terminate after current cmd ends)

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

I have problem with mongoDB in Amazon Elastic Container Service, i don't have problem while i running the container in my local machine, but the problem started when i start the task in amazon ECS.

I'm using mongodb 2.6.12

[image]

Comment: Share the error logs please

Comment: I already add the error logs

Comment: Is Fork set true in config file ?

Comment: `ERROR: child process failed, exited with error number 1
note: noprealloc may hurt performance in many applications
about to fork child process, waiting until server is ready for connections.
forked process: 7` this happpen when i set fork true